# What data must be sent after sending a STARTTLS command to an email server

Tags: c++, windows, email, winsock2, tls1.2

I am writing an email client in C++ using the Winsock2 API to send emails via SMTP from a Gmail account. I am not using any other third party libraries.

I have connected to the Gmail server on port 587 (for TLS) and sent the basic EHLO and STARTTLS commands, but my question is this, what data should I specifically send after I have sent the STARTTLS command?

This is the server output for clarity:

[image: This is the server output for clarity]

Obviously the TLS handshake goes after the STARTTLS command, but what is the first and subsequent pieces of data that must be sent during the TLS handshake? From what I've read it should be binary data exchanging security certificates etc but I could not find specifically what data should be sent first.

I have searched numerous similar questions to this but I haven't found an answer that has said the **specific** data that must be sent after STARTTLS. I am aware of the existence of OpenSSL and I am not going to accept any answers telling my to install it instead.

Answer (score 3):

The semantics and processing rules of the SMTP `STARTTLS` command are documented in [RFC 3207](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3207).

After you have received a successful 220 response to the `STARTTLS` command, you must then begin a TLS handshake to establish encryption with which to encrypt/decrypt subsequent SMTP commands/responses. Upon completion of the handshake, the SMTP state is reset, so you must issue a new (now encrypted) `EHLO` command, and then proceed with your remaining (encrypted) SMTP commands as needed.

MSDN documents a high-level overview of the [Transport Layer Security Protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380516.aspx), with step-by-step instructions for the [TLS Handshake Protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380513.aspx).  The specific details of each step are documented in Section 7 of [RFC 2246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2246) (TLS 1.0), [RFC 4346](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346) (TLS 1.1), and [RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) (TLS 1.2).

So, unless you are planning on implementing TLS from scratch (please don't !!), you need to use a third-party library, such as OpenSSL, or you can use Microsoft's [Secure Channel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380123.aspx) API, to handle the TLS handshake and subsequent encryption for you.

Comment: Please read my question carefully. I already know that I must perform a TLS handshake after the STARTTLS command, I am asking specifically what data I should send for the handshake. I have read the RFC's given but it still does not tell me what data to send. E.g. it specifies that I must send a certificate structure after getting a reply from the server but I have tried that and just got a "Ready to start tls" reply from the server. Again I am asking for the data to send specifically after STARTLS for the TLS handshake with the email server.

Comment: @shmoo: I did read your question. If you pay attention to the RFCs I pointed out, they tell you exactly WHAT to send and WHEN to send it. You can't perform the TLS handshake unless the server sends a `STARTTLS` 220 reply first, as defined in RFC 3207. THEN perform the handshake, starting with sending the TLS `ClientHello` record and receiving the `ServerHello` record, as defined in Section 7 ("the TLS Handshake Protocol") of RFCs 2246, 4346, and 5246.  You need to read the RFCs more carefully, the answers you are looking for ARE documented in them.

Comment: @shmoo: if you read the MSDN documentation I pointed out, it gives you a very clear overview of the TLS handshake step-by-step.  The RFCs give you the specific technical details (format and content) of each step.

Comment: @shmoo Yuor comment is ridiculous. These *are* the TLS RFCs. If you think they don't detail the handshake, you can't have read them. But if you're looking to implement SSL yourself you should forget that now. Use OpenSSL or one of the other existing libraries. It is a huge job.

Comment: No, ClientHello does not work after sending the STARTTLS command and yes I have read the RFCs but nothing I send is accepted by the server

Comment: I've also tried sending the ClientHello structure detailed in the RFCs as the first data to be sent but again I get no reply from the server.

Comment: @shmoo: I assure you that sending a `ClientHello` immediately after receiving the `STARTTLS` 220 response DOES work. Every TLS-enabled SMTP client app does it. If it is not working for you, you are doing something wrong. All the more reason to NOT implement TLS manually, let an established library handle the hard work for you. But, if you insist on doing it yourself, I suggest you use WireShark to look at a working TLS handshake from an existing SMTP client, and then replicate the necessary messaging in your own app. That will also show you what is wrong with your handshake messages.

Comment: I assure you that sending a ClientHello does not work after STARTTLS. The RFC says if the server isn't satisfied with the response it SHOULD send a fatal alert and close the connection, but I haven't received a fatal alert and the connection with the server remains open. However, I will have a look at WireShark to see if I get can any further ideas thank you.

Comment: Yes, `ClientHello` DOES WORK, otherwise **EVERY** TLS-enabled SMTP would be failing. You are clearly doing something wrong with your `ClientHello`. My guess is you are probably not sending it correctly, so the server is still waiting for you to finish sending it. But since you have not shown *any* of your code, noone here can tell you what you are actually doing wrong.